# What values are actually used for the kernel when using a Conv2D layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to fully understand what a Conv2D layer actually does and I think I got most of it. But theres one thing I don't quite get. When reading about Kernels there were multiple mentions that for example a `(3,3)` kernel, like this one

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\\\
-1 & 5 & -1 \\\\
0 & -1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

is useful for e.g. sharpening an image.

But when I want to use a Conv2D layer in TensorFlow I don't have to specify this anywhere. Something like this is sufficient:

`tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(4, 3, padding="same", activation="relu")`

So what values are used for the kernel by default? Or am I missunderstanding this whole thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are **learned** during the training. Initially, they are given random values, then by means of back-propagation and gradient descent, the values of the kernels are adjusted during several iterations to make the final results as close as possible to the expected results.

Comment: Thanks! Not saying you are wrong by any means, but do you also have a good source confirming and elaborating on this that one could cite from?

Comment: Well, this is very basic stuff, so every neural network course goes through this. Maybe you can use [the convolutional networks section of the famous CS231N course on neural networks from Standford](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv). Or directly [the article _ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks_ by Krizhevsky et al. in 2012](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2012/file/c399862d3b9d6b76c8436e924a68c45b-Paper.pdf), which started the trend of using deep learning; there you can see on figure 3 an illustration of the learned filters.